# I am getting error while running the flutter project for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I am getting below output error while  running the flutter project in iOS.

This error is related to Cocoapods.

Please guide me how should I resolve it.

Earlier error was related to iOS version 8.0 which I upgraded to 9.0 , after that I am facing this issue and getting error while running for iOS

```
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `mapbox_gl` from `.symlinks/plugins/mapbox_gl/ios`
    [!] No podspec found for `mapbox_gl` in `.symlinks/plugins/mapbox_gl/ios`

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:989:in `fetch_external_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:968:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:966:in `fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'


Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to uncomment `platform :ios, '9.0'` by removing `#` in your podfile. Then re-install pods.

Comment: Sorry it didn't helped me as of now, I did as you said, run `flutter clean` and then tried to install the app and the same error I got again

Comment: Sometimes, `flutter clean` is not enough itself. You can try to delete ios/Podfile.lock, ios/Pods, ios/Flutter/App.Framework too.

Comment: you mean ios/Flutter/Flutter.Framework ??

Comment: Yes, you're right! Delete ios/Flutter/Flutter.Framework too.

Comment: It's work for me 
*1. delete podfile.lock
*2. delete pod folder
*3. flutter clean 
*4. pub get
*5. pod install